# convert js escaped char (or hex char?) in json_decoded string to html entity in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, string, encoding

I have:
`<?php
$results = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://....`

Within the echoed $results string, I get \xe9 instead of é, \xb0 instead of N°.
I'm not sure what format the string I'm receiving is in? Since it's json, maybe this is javascript escaped special characters? If so, how would I go about unescaping it (and where)? I tried it in the ajax call (`html.(unescape(data))`) but that didn't work. Many of the posts I've read with similar issues suggest php's mb_convert_encoding() but I don't know what I'm trying to convert from ( or to, actually... html entities?) and it seems to take specific strings rather than an all characters with that format (\ xxx)?  Thanks for any insights.

Comment: json is always utf-8.

Comment: make sure that your html encoding is utf-8 and you will get the proper output without any conversion.

Comment: @steven Thanks, this is in WordPress which always uses utf-8 (confirmed in the db, too)

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are dealing with non-standard json. it is best if you can utf8ize the json before you encode it. but if it is in another server and you cannot access it, you can encode what you get from json to UTF8

```
$results = utf8_encode(json_decode("http://...
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it didn't impact anything.

Comment: I used mb_detect_encoding on the output of file_get_contents and it returned ascii; so, I tried `$utf8str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "ASCII", "UTF-8");` and the same characters still appear as escaped javascript...

Comment: I suspect uft8_encode cannot encode your json_decode because json_decode is an array. You can try putting utf8_encode before running json_decode and see if it works? Also you can use run utf8_encode on arrays:
function utf8_encode_array($array) {
    return array_map('utf8_encode', $array);
}
$encoded_array = array_walk_recursive('utf8_encode_array', $your_array);